# Не работают карты OpenStreetMap в админке сайта

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток.
В админке Wordpress и при добавлении анкеты на сайте не работают карты OpenStreetMap. Сама карта есть, но она просто серая и на ней метка, т.е. определить место невозможно. Но при добавлении широты и долготы в админке, пользователи на самом сайте могут видеть карту нормально.

Вот так при заполнении анкеты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так на самом сайте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли вот такая ошибка: Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js?ver=1.5.1:35 Uncaught (in promise) Error: window.google not found after 10 attempts at Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js?ver=1.5.1:35

В js я совсем не понимаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно с этим сделать?

```
// Based on https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins
// GridLayer like https://avinmathew.com/leaflet-and-google-maps/ , but using MutationObserver instead of jQuery


// class GridLayer.GoogleMutant
// extends GridLayer
L.GridLayer.GoogleMutant = L.GridLayer.extend({
    options: {
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 23,
        tileSize: 256,
        subdomains: 'abc',
        errorTileUrl: '',
        attribution: '',    // The mutant container will add its own attribution anyways.
        opacity: 1,
        continuousWorld: false,
        noWrap: false,
        // option type: String = 'roadmap'
        // Google's map type. Valid values are 'roadmap', 'satellite' or 'terrain'. 'hybrid' is not really supported.
        type: 'roadmap',
        maxNativeZoom: 21
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        L.GridLayer.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);

        this._ready = !!window.google && !!window.google.maps && !!window.google.maps.Map;

        this._GAPIPromise = this._ready ? Promise.resolve(window.google) : new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var checkCounter = 0;
            var intervalId = null;
            intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                if (checkCounter >= 10) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    return reject(new Error('window.google not found after 10 attempts'));
                }
                if (!!window.google && !!window.google.maps && !!window.google.maps.Map) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    return resolve(window.google);
                }
                checkCounter++;
            }, 500);
        });

        // Couple data structures indexed by tile key
        this._tileCallbacks = {};   // Callbacks for promises for tiles that are expected
        this._freshTiles = {};  // Tiles from the mutant which haven't been requested yet

        this._imagesPerTile = (this.options.type === 'hybrid') ? 2 : 1;

        this._boundOnMutatedImage = this._onMutatedImage.bind(this);
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        L.GridLayer.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
        this._initMutantContainer();

        this._GAPIPromise.then(function () {
            this._ready = true;
            this._map = map;

            this._initMutant();

            map.on('viewreset', this._reset, this);
            if (this.options.updateWhenIdle) {
                map.on('moveend', this._update, this);
            } else {
                map.on('move', this._update, this);
            }
            map.on('zoomend', this._handleZoomAnim, this);
            map.on('resize', this._resize, this);

            //handle layer being added to a map for which there are no Google tiles at the given zoom
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this._mutant, 'idle', function () {
                this._checkZoomLevels();
                this._mutantIsReady = true;
            }.bind(this));

            //20px instead of 1em to avoid a slight overlap with google's attribution
            map._controlCorners.bottomright.style.marginBottom = '20px';
            map._controlCorners.bottomleft.style.marginBottom = '20px';

            this._reset();
            this._update();

            if (this._subLayers) {
                //restore previously added google layers
                for (var layerName in this._subLayers) {
                    this._subLayers[layerName].setMap(this._mutant);
                }
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },

    onRemove: function (map) {
        L.GridLayer.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
        this._observer.disconnect();
        map._container.removeChild(this._mutantContainer);

        google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'idle');
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(this._mutant, 'idle');
        map.off('viewreset', this._reset, this);
        map.off('move', this._update, this);
        map.off('moveend', this._update, this);
        map.off('zoomend', this._handleZoomAnim, this);
        map.off('resize', this._resize, this);

        if (map._controlCorners) {
            map._controlCorners.bottomright.style.marginBottom = '0em';
            map._controlCorners.bottomleft.style.marginBottom = '0em';
        }
    },

    getAttribution: function () {
        return this.options.attribution;
    },

    setElementSize: function (e, size) {
        e.style.width = size.x + 'px';
        e.style.height = size.y + 'px';
    },


    addGoogleLayer: function (googleLayerName, options) {
        if (!this._subLayers) this._subLayers = {};
        return this._GAPIPromise.then(function () {
            var Constructor = google.maps[googleLayerName];
            var googleLayer = new Constructor(options);
            googleLayer.setMap(this._mutant);
            this._subLayers[googleLayerName] = googleLayer;
            return googleLayer;
        }.bind(this));
    },

    removeGoogleLayer: function (googleLayerName) {
        var googleLayer = this._subLayers && this._subLayers[googleLayerName];
        if (!googleLayer) return;

        googleLayer.setMap(null);
        delete this._subLayers[googleLayerName];
    },


    _initMutantContainer: function () {
        if (!this._mutantContainer) {
            this._mutantContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-google-mutant leaflet-top leaflet-left');
            this._mutantContainer.id = '_MutantContainer_' + L.Util.stamp(this._mutantContainer);
            this._mutantContainer.style.zIndex = '800'; //leaflet map pane at 400, controls at 1000
            this._mutantContainer.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            
            L.DomEvent.off(this._mutantContainer);

        }
        this._map.getContainer().appendChild(this._mutantContainer);

        this.setOpacity(this.options.opacity);
        this.setElementSize(this._mutantContainer, this._map.getSize());

        this._attachObserver(this._mutantContainer);
    },

    _initMutant: function () {
        if (!this._ready || !this._mutantContainer) return;

        if (this._mutant) {
            // reuse old _mutant, just make sure it has the correct size
            this._resize();
            return;
        }

        this._mutantCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(this._mutantContainer, {
            center: this._mutantCenter,
            zoom: 0,
            tilt: 0,
            mapTypeId: this.options.type,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            keyboardShortcuts: false,
            draggable: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            styles: this.options.styles || {},
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        });

        this._mutant = map;

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
            var nodes = this._mutantContainer.querySelectorAll('a');
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                nodes[i].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
            }
        }.bind(this));

        // event spawned
        // Fired when the mutant has been created.
        this.fire('spawned', {mapObject: map});
    },

    _attachObserver: function _attachObserver (node) {
//      console.log('Gonna observe', node);

        if (!this._observer)
            this._observer = new MutationObserver(this._onMutations.bind(this));

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        this._observer.observe(node, { childList: true, subtree: true });

        // if we are reusing an old _mutantContainer, we must manually detect
        // all existing tiles in it
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
            node.querySelectorAll('img'),
            this._boundOnMutatedImage
        );
    },

    _onMutations: function _onMutations (mutations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; ++i) {
            var mutation = mutations[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < mutation.addedNodes.length; ++j) {
                var node = mutation.addedNodes[j];

                if (node instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
                    this._onMutatedImage(node);
                } else if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                        node.querySelectorAll('img'),
                        this._boundOnMutatedImage
                    );

                    // Check for, and remove, the "Google Maps can't load correctly" div.
                    // You *are* loading correctly, you dumbwit.
                    if (node.style.backgroundColor === 'white') {
                        L.DomUtil.remove(node);
                    }
                    
                    // Check for, and remove, the "For development purposes only" divs on the aerial/hybrid tiles.
                    if (node.textContent.indexOf('For development purposes only') === 0) {
                        L.DomUtil.remove(node);
                    }
                    
                    // Check for, and remove, the "Sorry, we have no imagery here"
                    // empty <div>s. The [style*="text-align: center"] selector
                    // avoids matching the attribution notice.
                    // This empty div doesn't have a reference to the tile
                    // coordinates, so it's not possible to mark the tile as
                    // failed.
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                        node.querySelectorAll('div[draggable=false][style*="text-align: center"]'),
                        L.DomUtil.remove
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Only images which 'src' attrib match this will be considered for moving around.
    // Looks like some kind of string-based protobuf, maybe??
    // Only the roads (and terrain, and vector-based stuff) match this pattern
    _roadRegexp: /!1i(\d+)!2i(\d+)!3i(\d+)!/,

    // On the other hand, raster imagery matches this other pattern
    _satRegexp: /x=(\d+)&y=(\d+)&z=(\d+)/,

    // On small viewports, when zooming in/out, a static image is requested
    // This will not be moved around, just removed from the DOM.
    _staticRegExp: /StaticMapService\.GetMapImage/,

    _onMutatedImage: function _onMutatedImage (imgNode) {
//      if (imgNode.src) {
//          console.log('caught mutated image: ', imgNode.src);
//      }

        var coords;
        var match = imgNode.src.match(this._roadRegexp);
        var sublayer = 0;

        if (match) {
            coords = {
                z: match[1],
                x: match[2],
                y: match[3]
            };
            if (this._imagesPerTile > 1) { 
                imgNode.style.zIndex = 1;
                sublayer = 1;
            }
        } else {
            match = imgNode.src.match(this._satRegexp);
            if (match) {
                coords = {
                    x: match[1],
                    y: match[2],
                    z: match[3]
                };
            }
//          imgNode.style.zIndex = 0;
            sublayer = 0;
        }

        if (coords) {
            var tileKey = this._tileCoordsToKey(coords);
            imgNode.style.position = 'absolute';
            imgNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';

            var key = tileKey + '/' + sublayer;
            // console.log('mutation for tile', key)
            //store img so it can also be used in subsequent tile requests
            this._freshTiles[key] = imgNode;

            if (key in this._tileCallbacks && this._tileCallbacks[key]) {
// console.log('Fullfilling callback ', key);
                //fullfill most recent tileCallback because there maybe callbacks that will never get a 
                //corresponding mutation (because map moved to quickly...)
                this._tileCallbacks[key].pop()(imgNode); 
                if (!this._tileCallbacks[key].length) { delete this._tileCallbacks[key]; }
            } else {
                if (this._tiles[tileKey]) {
                    //we already have a tile in this position (mutation is probably a google layer being added)
                    //replace it
                    var c = this._tiles[tileKey].el;
                    var oldImg = (sublayer === 0) ? c.firstChild : c.firstChild.nextSibling;
                    var cloneImgNode = this._clone(imgNode);
                    c.replaceChild(cloneImgNode, oldImg);
                }
            }
        } else if (imgNode.src.match(this._staticRegExp)) {
            imgNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    },


    createTile: function (coords, done) {
        var key = this._tileCoordsToKey(coords);

        var tileContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div');
        tileContainer.dataset.pending = this._imagesPerTile;
        done = done.bind(this, null, tileContainer);

        for (var i = 0; i < this._imagesPerTile; i++) {
            var key2 = key + '/' + i;
            if (key2 in this._freshTiles) {
                var imgNode = this._freshTiles[key2];
                tileContainer.appendChild(this._clone(imgNode));
                tileContainer.dataset.pending--;
//              console.log('Got ', key2, ' from _freshTiles');
            } else {
                this._tileCallbacks[key2] = this._tileCallbacks[key2] || [];
                this._tileCallbacks[key2].push( (function (c/*, k2*/) {
                    return function (imgNode) {
                        c.appendChild(this._clone(imgNode));
                        c.dataset.pending--;
                        if (!parseInt(c.dataset.pending)) { done(); }
//                      console.log('Sent ', k2, ' to _tileCallbacks, still ', c.dataset.pending, ' images to go');
                    }.bind(this);
                }.bind(this))(tileContainer/*, key2*/) );
            }
        }

        if (!parseInt(tileContainer.dataset.pending)) {
            L.Util.requestAnimFrame(done);
        }
        return tileContainer;
    },

    _clone: function (imgNode) {
        var clonedImgNode = imgNode.cloneNode(true);
        clonedImgNode.style.visibility = 'visible';
        return clonedImgNode;
    },

    _checkZoomLevels: function () {
        //setting the zoom level on the Google map may result in a different zoom level than the one requested
        //(it won't go beyond the level for which they have data).
        var zoomLevel = this._map.getZoom();
        var gMapZoomLevel = this._mutant.getZoom();
        if (!zoomLevel || !gMapZoomLevel) return;


        if ((gMapZoomLevel !== zoomLevel) || //zoom levels are out of sync, Google doesn't have data
            (gMapZoomLevel > this.options.maxNativeZoom)) { //at current location, Google does have data (contrary to maxNativeZoom)
            //Update maxNativeZoom
            this._setMaxNativeZoom(gMapZoomLevel);
        }
    },

    _setMaxNativeZoom: function (zoomLevel) {
        if (zoomLevel != this.options.maxNativeZoom) {
            this.options.maxNativeZoom = zoomLevel;
            this._resetView();
        }
    },

    _reset: function () {
        this._initContainer();
    },

    _update: function () {
        // zoom level check needs to happen before super's implementation (tile addition/creation)
        // otherwise tiles may be missed if maxNativeZoom is not yet correctly determined
        if (this._mutant) {
            var center = this._map.getCenter();
            var _center = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat, center.lng);

            this._mutant.setCenter(_center);
            var zoom = this._map.getZoom();
            var fractionalLevel = zoom !== Math.round(zoom);
            var mutantZoom = this._mutant.getZoom();

            //ignore fractional zoom levels
            if (!fractionalLevel && (zoom != mutantZoom)) {
                this._mutant.setZoom(zoom);
                            
                if (this._mutantIsReady) this._checkZoomLevels();
                //else zoom level check will be done later by 'idle' handler
            }
        }

        L.GridLayer.prototype._update.call(this);
    },

    _resize: function () {
        var size = this._map.getSize();
        if (this._mutantContainer.style.width === size.x &&
            this._mutantContainer.style.height === size.y)
            return;
        this.setElementSize(this._mutantContainer, size);
        if (!this._mutant) return;
        google.maps.event.trigger(this._mutant, 'resize');
    },

    _handleZoomAnim: function () {
        if (!this._mutant) return;
        var center = this._map.getCenter();
        var _center = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat, center.lng);

        this._mutant.setCenter(_center);
        this._mutant.setZoom(Math.round(this._map.getZoom()));
    },

    // Agressively prune _freshtiles when a tile with the same key is removed,
    // this prevents a problem where Leaflet keeps a loaded tile longer than
    // GMaps, so that GMaps makes two requests but Leaflet only consumes one,
    // polluting _freshTiles with stale data.
    _removeTile: function (key) {
        if (!this._mutant) return;

        //give time for animations to finish before checking it tile should be pruned
        setTimeout(this._pruneTile.bind(this, key), 1000);


        return L.GridLayer.prototype._removeTile.call(this, key);
    },

    _pruneTile: function (key) {
        var gZoom = this._mutant.getZoom();
        var tileZoom = key.split(':')[2];
        var googleBounds = this._mutant.getBounds();
        var sw = googleBounds.getSouthWest();
        var ne = googleBounds.getNorthEast();
        var gMapBounds = L.latLngBounds([[sw.lat(), sw.lng()], [ne.lat(), ne.lng()]]);

        for (var i=0; i<this._imagesPerTile; i++) {
            var key2 = key + '/' + i;
            if (key2 in this._freshTiles) { 
                var tileBounds = this._map && this._keyToBounds(key);
                var stillVisible = this._map && tileBounds.overlaps(gMapBounds) && (tileZoom == gZoom);

                if (!stillVisible) delete this._freshTiles[key2]; 
//              console.log('Prunning of ', key, (!stillVisible))
            }
        }
    }
});


// factory gridLayer.googleMutant(options)
// Returns a new `GridLayer.GoogleMutant` given its options
L.gridLayer.googleMutant = function (options) {
    return new L.GridLayer.GoogleMutant(options);
};
```

Comment: в админку не подключен скрипт гугл карты т.е. не хватает `<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>` вместо `YOUR_API_KEY` должен ваш ключ стоять

Comment: @Greg-- Спасибо. Как я на это не обратил внимания? Видимо жара даёт о себе знать. Теперь всё работает.

Comment: да обычно в бэкэнд карту не ставят